# What are the main long-standing Keynesian economic programmes in Western nations?

Tags: welfare-economics, government-spending

Much of US military spending is more easily rationalised as a job-creating programme than a form of defence, e.g. vehicles Congress funds despite Pentagon insisting it doesn't need or want them or have anywhere to store them. Part of the reason the US spends far more on the military than other Western nations ([3.3% of GDP vs 2% or less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_military_expenditures)) is that, in the United States, the military is an especially socially acceptable source of welfare. As a UK citizen I find this plausible, but it occurs to me that I have no idea what the UK government spends money on as much for the jobs as for the apparent application. Which leads to my question: what forms of spending do different Western nations use with Keynesian motive?